# Change class name using jquery for Bootstrap class

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

While the tab is active i want to change class from iconcolorblack to iconcolorwhite but i am not getting it. how to do that:

```
<div class="navbar-inner main-nav-lower" >
     <ul class="nav nav-pills navcolor">
        <li id="jobsHead"><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">
           <i class="fa fa-clock-o iconSizeMedium iconColorblack"></i>Jobs</a></li>
             <li id="ManageData"><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">
                <i class="fa fa-cog iconSizeMedium iconColorblack"></i>Manage Data</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I have used:

```
 $("#ManageData").find("iconColorblack").addClass("iconColorwhite").remove("iconColorblack");
```

But its not seems to be working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change

```
$("#ManageData").find("iconColorblack").addClass("iconColoorwhite").remove("iconColorblack");
```

to

```
$("#ManageData").find(".iconColorblack").addClass("iconColorwhite").removeClass("iconColorblack");
```

perhaps?

Comment: sorry its seems i have written wrongly in question. i have changed can you please help